# Supertest in Cucumber delay

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, supertest, cucumberjs

I'm using supertest in cucumber step files to make a request to my API running in docker. Also, I'm using a Scenario Outline with Examples so the request is made 4 times.

EDIT: I found that on the first request in cucumber I get this error in my docker logs: 'failed to establish 9P connection: Caught EOF on underlying FLOW'. But it only happens once and never from the browser or Postman.

given.js:

```
const request = require('supertest');

module.exports = function givens() {
  this.Given(/^then system is active$/, function (callback) {
    this.request = request.agent('http://localhost:8787');
    callback();
  });
}
```

then:

```
module.exports = function whens() {
  this.When(/^the client requests a list of questions with the parameters of "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$/,
    function (companyId, state, propertyType, yearBuilt, floodZone, active, callback) {
      var json = {
        ...
      };

    this.request.post('/questions')
      .send(json)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(err);
        //return callback();
      });
  });
}
```

The problem is that there is a delay in the response. The first request returns an error:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:254:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ECONNRESET', response: undefined }
```

But if I take out the callbacks it will get the correct responses after a delay. What is causing the first request to hang up? The API request works fine in the browser and Postman.